# hashtable and synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, hashtable

I have read that hashtables are thread-safe because it is synchronized. consider this code snippet

```
if(!hashtable.contains(key)){
hashtable.put(key,value);
}
```

The operations on hashtable may not be synchronized. for example, if `Thread t1` access the hastable and check for key and at the same time `Thread t2` checks for key, before t1 executes put. now two threads are inside the if block and overwriting of key-value happens.

so synchronized block is necessary.

```
synchronized {
if(!hashtable.contains(key)){
    hashtable.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

Is this understanding correct? or is hastables safe on the operations that is performed upon hastables. I got this doubt while I was reading this [post on race condition](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2012/02/what-is-race-condition-in.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that you need the `synchronized` block. The `Hashtable's` methods are `synchronized`, but you still have the possibility of having a race when calling multiple methods outside of a `synchronized` block. The built-in synchronization prevents problems when two threads call `put` at the same time for example.

You might also want to look into `ConcurrentHashMap`

Answer (score 4):

`Hashtable` methods are synchronized, but that only provides method-level protection against race conditions. (So a `Hashtable`—unlike a `HashMap`—will not become internally corrupted if multiple threads are concurrently trying to modify the data.) It is only in this sense that `Hashtable` is thread-safe.

Neither `Hashtable` nor a `ConcurrentHashMap` will provide higher-level synchronization, which is usually<sup>*</sup> what you need when you are performing multi-step operations. You need an external `synchronized` block anyway, so you might as well use the lower-overhead `HashMap` rather than a `Hashtable`.

<sup>*</sup><sub>As Jeff Storey points out, `ConcurrentHashMap` has a `putIfAbsent` method that does exactly what you are doing in your code. For other multi-step operations, `ConcurrentHashMap` may or may not have a method that does what you need atomically.</sub>

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` has a `putIfAbsent` method that will atomically check for containment of the key and put it if it does not exist

Comment: @JeffStorey - Yes, forgot about that. Thank you. I'll update my answer accordingly. Still, for other multi-step operations, external synchronization may be needed.